# Live barcode scanning in WP7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, barcode, scanning

We are using ZXing library for scanning barcodes in our WP7.5 application. I want to know whether there is any library which allows live scanning in Mango. I heard that there were private libraries to do this, but are these published yet?

Comment: What do you mean by live scanning? If you simply start a Camera task and register for the captured frames you can analyze them using any library you want.

Comment: I mean the camera should not capture the snapshot and then analyse it. It should be able to show results within the camera screen while scannning the barcode at the same time. Just like the eye icon in Bing Search on WP7

Comment: You can do that by passing the frame to an image control. Thereby making your own camera screen.

Comment: Erno, instead of comments please use answers section to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I did this today and ended up using the instructions from Jonas Follesø

http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/qr-code-scanning-on-windows-phone-75-using-zxlib/

Edit:
The above code can be modified to use the appropiate type of Reader (depending on what you need). I changed my reader app to use the UPCAReader() instead of QRCodeReader(). If you know what type you want you can probably find an appropiate reader in namespace com.google.zxing.oned. There is a more generic OneDReader which might help too.

Comment: What do you mean by BarCode scanning? Jonas's instructions take the preview buffer of the PhotoCamera every 250ms and pass it to the QRCodeReader class in the ZXing library for it to decode. This gives you back the result points of the QR code which I am overlaying on the screen preview from the camera.

Comment: This works for QR scanning, but is there a way we could do this for barcode scanning?

Comment: @RashiAnand yes, you just need to change the which zx reader class you are passing the images too...